# replace the span html text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I had the html like below

```
<input id="id_wow" placeholder="0.0" type="text" name="{{state.0}}" value="{{tax_value}}" class="must_be_float">
<br><span class="id_wow">hrray</span>
```

so when a user enters a value in input field other than float, i should fill this span text with `"It must be float"`, but my jquery code is not working

**jquery code**

```
  $('.must_be_float').focusout(function() {
       var class =  $('.must_be_float').attr('id');
       var value = $('.must_be_float').val();
       if (value)
         {
          float_or_not = parseFloat(value);
          if(isNaN(float_or_not))
             {
              $('span.class').html('Value must be float');
             }
         }  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('span.id_wow').html('Value must be float');
```

or

```
$('span.'+class).html('Value must be float');
```

In Jquery, the selector for a class is "."
Check it out [Jquery Class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('span[class="id_wow"]').html('Value must be float');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

here i had made some changes in your code. now it work's fine.

HTML

```
<input id="id_wow" placeholder="0.0" type="text" name="{{state.0}}" value="{{tax_value}}" class="must_be_float">
<br><span Id="Msg" class="id_wow">hrray</span>
```

JQ

```
$("#id_wow").blur(function(event) {

      // var class =  $('.must_be_float').attr('id'); no need
     var value = $("#id_wow").val();     
     if( (value == +value) && (value != (value/0)) && (!isNaN(value)))
     {
         $("#Msg").text("Good It is Float a value");
     }
     else
     {
        $("#Msg").text("Value must be float");
     }

  });
```

### [Click Here For **Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vL2gB/4/)

Also if u need textbox that accept only Float value:

Check this [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/VRa6n/)

If this is what you need put a **Reply..**

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong name for class in selector.

```
$('.id_wow').html('Value must be float');
```

Comment: the span has a class the selector should use a . not #

Comment: Thanks @MarkWalters, confucing class name, updated my answer.

Comment: No worries, I agree the example was confusing though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.id_wow').html('Value must be float');
//^^^^span then its classnme with "."
```

REFERENCE **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
$('span.'+class).html('Value must be float');
```

But I did not test it.